# VBA Filter MM/YYYY based on User Input

Tags: vba, excel, filter

I have a huge set of data from which i have to filter data for specific month at any point of time. the idea is to have a pop up that asked which month the report should be generated, then the value is used to filter the required data. Better still if i can get excel to only give me the data for that month and delete the rest. (about 80K lines with dates from 2014 to current).

```
Sub FilterByReportingMonth()

Dim wsreport As Worksheet
Dim ReportingMonth As String
Dim UserInputMonth As Long

Set wsreport = Sheets("Report")

    Range("U:U").NumberFormat = "mm/yyyy"

    ReportingMonth = InputBox("Which month's Classroom Report do you want to generate? Please provide in mm/yyyy format.")
    If ReportingMonth = vbNullString Then Exit Sub

    If Not IsDate(ReportingMonth) Then
       MsgBox "That is not a valid date. Please use mm/yyyy format"
       Run "FilterByDateRange"
    End If

    UserInputMonth = CDate(ReportingMonth)

    'the below is in red and i get a syntax error

    wsreport.Range("$A$9:$AF$99999").AutoFilter Field:=21, Criteria1:= _
        "UserInputMonth", Operator:=xlAnd,

    If ActiveSheet.FilterMode Then
        ActiveSheet.ShowAllData
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Please edit your question, I don't understand the issue here. **"I am not sure which part is incorrect"** did the code gives you any error? If it does which line is being highlighted?

Comment: the Sub FilterByReportingMonth () is highlighted in yellow

Comment: which line is highlighted in yellow? And what is the specific message?

Comment: Also, how are you going to call this code? Will it need to open another file which is the one you want to delete rows and or keep only a specified month's data in? What happens if you make the wrong initial selection and you have then deleted the data?

Comment: the **Sub FilterByReportingMonth ()** is highlighted in yellow. I also put a comment in my code stating which line appears in red. Error message when i run the code is "Compile Error: Syntax Error"

Comment: Your current error is due to Operator:=xlAnd, <===== the end "," indicates a parameter is expected to follow after this. Either add the next named parameter or remove the trailing ","

Comment: the data is in the "Report" sheet in the active workbook. it will not open another book. I have done most part of it, there are some codes to execute simple and/or redundant tasks before and after this code. basically, the data in the "Report" sheet needs to be cleaned, remove unwanted info and filter/keep only those which are needed.

Comment: Next:  UserInputMonth is  a variable so do not place between "" in the filter i.e.  Criteria1:=UserInputMonth

Comment: Will a new Report sheet be added to the workbook each month? Or the data overwritten?

Comment: a new report will be generated every month, so every month we will have a new file. I did as you mentioned, and run the code again, i got the pop-up to fill the mm/yyyy but i get **"Run-time error '424': Object required. the below is highlighted in yellow**
        AtiveSheet.Range("$A$9:$AF$99999").AutoFilter Field:=21, Criteria1:=UserInputMonth

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Start with something like the following:

```
Option Explicit

Sub FilterByReportingMonth()

    Dim wsreport As Worksheet
    Dim ReportingMonth As String
    Dim UserInputMonth As Date

    Set wsreport = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Report") 'assuming code in same workbook as data 

    With wsreport

        .Range("U:U").NumberFormat = "mm/yyyy"

        ReportingMonth = InputBox("Which month's Classroom Report do you want to generate? Please provide in mm/yyyy format.")
        If ReportingMonth = vbNullString Then Exit Sub

        If Not IsDate(ReportingMonth) Then
            MsgBox "That is not a valid date. Please use mm/yyyy format"
            Run "FilterByDateRange"
        End If

        UserInputMonth = CDate(ReportingMonth)

        .Range("$A$9:$AF$99999").AutoFilter

        .Range("$A$9:$AF$99999").AutoFilter Field:=21, Operator:= _
                                            xlFilterValues,
    Criteria1:=Format$(UserInputMonth, "mm/yyyy")
    End With

End Sub
```